# ¿Es posible darle estilo visual a un texto con código HTML en un JOptionPane?

Tags: java, html

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hola Mundo"); //mensaje simple
```

Comment: Buenas, revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: El código que muestras es para texto simple (`Hola Mundo`). ¿Has probado a poner HTML (p.e. `<h1 style='color:red'>Hola Mundo</h1>`) en ese mismo código? ¿Qué ocurre si lo haces? Tu pregunta parece interesante y espero que no se cierre, pero tal y como está redactada parece que no hayas intentado absolutamente nada y eso puede hacer que algunos usuarios no la reciban bien y voten por cerrarla.

Comment: Hola gracias por la observación recientemente estuve intentando algunos codigos y me han funcionado de maravilla.

Comment: `String css = "<span style='font-size: 100; color: yellow; background color: black'>";
String batchCss = "<span style='font-size: 100;'>";
String endSpanCss = "</span>";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html>" + css + batchCss + " 1 " + endSpanCss + "of" + batchCss + " 2 " + endSpanCss + endSpanCss + "</html>");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que desea es darle formato o estilo al contenido de  este componente empleando `HTML` sí es posible. En la [documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)  especifica claramente que para esto solo tendría que emplear la etiqueta `<html>` al inicio y `</html>` al final *(como todo documento html)*

Como ejemplo para darle estilo visual a un texto *(como su pregunta requiere)* sería.

```
String mensaje = "<html><p style='color:blue;'>Hola EsStackoverflow</p></html>";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mensaje);
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probe  y me ha servido mucho, gracias nuevamente.